# How to elegantly poll/pull information from a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, algorithm, database-design

I am currently beginning a new personal project. I have a database that keeps track of users as they log in to my webpage. It shows when they log on and log off. It uses SQL Server 2008.

What I would like to do is, whenever a user logs in, a scrolling bar along the top of my webpage alerts me to this. I have created a dashboard to keep track of a lot of my website statistics and this is something I think would be really cool. Useless, ultimately - but it would produce a "heheh" from me every so often, so why not ?

Now, I have never attempted to build something like this (which is the reason I am building it!) so I am torn between a few different design approaches. It seems like I could poll the database server repeatedly using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx, just writing a query to find the set of currently logged in users and display any additions to that pool. If this is the right path to go down, then I would appreciate some more in-depth commentary on how this could be used.

From a high level perspective it seems like, rather than repeatedly polling the database, it would be more efficient to have the DB push the message out to my web server when there is a change. Would this be possible? If so, how ?

For the sake of argument, and to give this discussion a bit more specificity, let's assume our SQL Server tables are structured as follows (but feel free to make any improvements or changes as you see fit!):

```
Users {
ID Primary Key
Username(Varchar 100)
Password
}

LogInOrOutLogs {
SessionID Primary Key
UserID (Foreign Key)
TimeLoggedIn (DateTime)
TimeLoggedOut (DateTime)
CurrentlyLoggedIn(Bool)
}
```

Open to all technologies, all database structures, all design ideas. Go crazy! Only requirements : You have a DB of users which updates as they log in and out. Display the information on a web server as meaningfully, elegantly and simply as you can.

Thanks a lot, looking forward to reading peoples solutions for this problem.

Comment: Not sure who put a -1 on this, but it seems fairly harsh given that I gave a specific question and it's quite interesting to boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have look at Hibernate ? This is an elegante object layer over SQL database.
Then you can push triggers on your database to push the event. When you have a event to your data you send it to your web application via long query (it is an ajax query with very very very long timeout, the query is re-send after a event is receive).

A crazy design should also use a two way [messaging system](http://www.rabbitmq.com/), one for message incoming into the DB one for other outputing from DB.

If you really like crazy thing you could thing of cache using a DB4O database (a cache for your SQL Server) embedded into a [servicemix](http://servicemix.apache.org/) - [redhatfuse](http://fr.redhat.com/products/jbossenterprisemiddleware/fuse/). There easy way with servicemix because of the predeployed broker(activemq) and fuse with it's nice fabric system.